# Change aliases of filter items in Tableau

Tags: visualization, tableau

Data sample contains a single feature: random integer number from 1 to 4.

Is it possble to change `1,2,3,4` representation on the filter card to some custom names, say: `Type1,Type2,Type3,Type4`? (not changing data set)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it myself.

- Go to context menu right clicking to the dimension field.
- Go to **Aliases...** and change the labels.

[image]